# C# Trouble with event handlers on dieing threads

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, event-handling, rapi

First of all my Main is STAThread and i am not able to change this without facing problems with the rest of my code.

So, I am currently using Rapi2 To pull and push files between my Pda and Computer. Now since there is quite a bit of number crunching i would like to do this on a separate thread. First wat i do is create an **RemoteDeviceManager** and then make an Event Handler for when a device connects.

```
public void Initialize()
    {
        _deviceManager = new RemoteDeviceManager();
        _deviceManager.DeviceConnected += DeviceConnected;
    }
```

As you can see when my device connects it triggers **DeviceConnected**.
This is the class that i end up pulling and pushing a database and do some number work.

```
 private void DeviceConnected(object sender, RemoteDeviceConnectEventArgs e)
        {
           if (e.Device == null) return;
           ... (unimportant code)
        }
```

Now the problem here is that i would want to run the code inside **DeviceConnected** in a new thread but i am unable to access **e** inside the new thread since it was initialized outside that thread
[image]

So now wat i tried was make a new thread before calling Initialize.

```
public Watcher()
    {
        _dataThread = new Thread(Initialize);
        _dataThread.IsBackground = true;
        _dataThread.Name = "Data Thread";
        _dataThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.MTA);
        _dataThread.Start();
    }
```

But the thread dies and thus never fires my event handler.
I tried many different ways to make it work or keep my thread alive but without any success. I hope someone here is able to give me some hints.

Comment: Extract all the information you need from `e` on the main thread, and marshal *only that information* to the new thread in a threadsafe manner of your choosing.  **Treat a thread like a lightweight process**.  If you had to do your number crunching by starting a process, how would you send the necessary information to the new process?

Comment: @EricLippert Right so i tried to pass e as a parameter. DeviceConnected:
_dataThread = new Thread(RunSync)
_dataThread.Start(e.Device);
e being the device.

Then in RunSync i would make a thread but even passing it, and assigning it inside RunSync.After making the Thread it was no longer able to use it.

Right so i only check some data between 2 databases. The only thing that requires me to access e is to first pull the file to my pc, and after all the work is done push it back. I tried doing just the crunching on a new thread, but then it would push the file back to soon.

Comment: What version of .NET are you in?  If 4.5 or greater I would use a Task instead which will make this a far less headache.  You could also create the thread in the event as an anonymous method and use the e value.  However; this doesn't say the e value will remain the same.  If the object invoking the event is going to modify e when the handler is complete, since e is a reference type, it will be affected on the thread also and possibly cause a cross threading issue.  You may want to copy the data to a variable and work on the copied data in the thread.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII Sadly enough i am stuck in .net 3.5 though never looked at upgrading the project and if this would cause problems though.
Also good idea about passing some stuff over to new variable's i will see if i can get that to work.